# Add names of dataframes in a table

Tags: r, purrr

I want to add the names of the dataframes in a table of t-tests.
Here is my example-code:

```
t1 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100)
t2 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 1))
t3 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 2))
```

Now I turn them into one data frame (that can then be printed as a table) with the broom and purrr packages:

```
library(broom)
library(purrr)

tab <- map_df(list(t1, t2, t3), tidy)
```

Now I get this table:

```
 estimate    estimate1   estimate2  statistic      p.value parameter   conf.low  conf.high
1  0.07889713 -0.008136139 -0.08703327   0.535986 5.925840e-01  193.4152 -0.2114261  0.3692204
2 -0.84980010  0.132836627  0.98263673  -6.169076 3.913068e-09  194.2561 -1.1214809 -0.5781193
3 -1.95876967 -0.039048940  1.91972073 -13.270232 3.618929e-29  197.9963 -2.2498519 -1.6676875
               method alternative
1 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
2 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
3 Welch Two Sample t-test   two.sided
```

And finally I want to add the names of the dataframes (t1,t2,t3) in the first column. Can someone explain me how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

We can `set_names` first and then use the `.id` argument to add the column.

```
set.seed(123)

t1 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100))
t2 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 1))
t3 <- t.test(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 2))

library(broom)
library(purrr)

tab <- list(t1, t2, t3) %>%
  set_names(paste0("t", 1:3)) %>%
  map_dfr(tidy, .id = "Test")
tab
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#   Test  estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method          alternative
#   <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>           <chr>      
# 1 t1       0.198    0.0904    -0.108      1.49 1.38e- 1      197.  -0.0643     0.460 Welch Two Samp~ two.sided  
# 2 t2      -0.843    0.120      0.964     -5.99 9.79e- 9      196.  -1.12      -0.566 Welch Two Samp~ two.sided  
# 3 t3      -1.85     0.106      1.96     -13.6  4.31e-30      197.  -2.12      -1.58  Welch Two Samp~ two.sided
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ls()` and a simple regex to catch your tests, i.e.

```
v1 <- ls()[grepl('^t[0-9]+', ls())]
#[1] "t1" "t2" "t3"
```

You can then attach `v1` to your data frame as per usual (`df$namess <- v1`)

Answer (score 1):

With a named list, you'll get the names in the resulting table:

```
ll <- list(t1 = t1, t2 = t2, t3 = t3)
tab <-
  ll %>%
  map_df(tidy, .id = "id")
```